# Check env variables in serverless.yml file (Serverless Framework)

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

I am new to using serverless framework and I would like to check that env variables inside serverless.yml are changing according to the stage I am on. Here is what I have in serverless.yml:

```
service: items

custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: api.app.com
    certificateName: '*.api.app.com'
    basePath: ''
    stage: ${self:provider.stage} <=== (Variable to check)
    createRoute53Record: true
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
  serverless-iam-roles-per-function:
    defaultInherit: true
.......
provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs8.10
......
......
process_updates:
    handler: handler.processUpdates
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Action:
          - s3:*
        Resource:
          - "arn:aws:s3:::${file(./config.${self:provider.stage}.json):items_updates}/*"
```

Config.dev.json:

```
{
  "items_updates": "dev-items-updates"
}
```

Config.prod.json:

```
{
  "items_updates": "prod-items-updates"
}
```

So, I would like to know if there is a way to print the following variables 
 `${self:provider.stage}` and `${file(./config.${self:provider.stage}.json):items_updates}` when the deployment is happening. And is there best practice using different env with serverless framework?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

### Plugin?

If you want to tie into *Serverless* lifecycle events, and do stuff, one typical approach would be to [write a plugin](https://serverless.com/blog/writing-serverless-plugins/).

I found the learning curve with Serverless plugin development to be quite gentle, and would recommend writing one to any Serverless user that hasn't done so.

However, sometimes a plugin is overkill, or undesirable for other reasons.

### Workaround

One very handy (yet often overlooked) feature of Serverless is that it can [resolve variables from *javascript files*.](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-javascript-files)

Note the exported function with this signature:

```
module.exports = (serverless) => { ... }
```

This `serverless` object gives you access to all sorts of stuff:

- Command line args can be found on `serverless.processedInput.options`.
- Your service can be found at `serverless.service`.

### Concrete Case

In your case, you could either put your `${env}-items-updates` data directly into a `.js` function, or have your function read up the file(s).

For the sake of simplicity, I'll assume you're willing to stuff the data right into the function.  I'll also illustrate using only a singe `items-updates.js` file, rather than separate files per stage.

`items-updates.js:`

```
module.exports = (serverless) => {
    const stage = serverless.service.provider.stage;

    serverless.cli.log(`Resolving items-updates for stage ${stage}`);

    switch (stage) {
        case 'dev':
            return {};  // Your dev-items-updates here
        case 'prod':
            return {};  // Your prod-items-updates here
    }
}
```

Then in your `iamRoleStatements`:

```
Resource:
  - ${file(./items-updates.js)}
```

*Note:* While the example above shows a default export, I do typically use named exports, so I can put more than one resource in a single js file.