# How to pass stage to handler.py from serverless.yml function in serverless framework

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have some functions configured using the serverless framework yaml file, for this I'm using a --stage flag in the command line script which is then set in the correct place in the serverless file to deploy to the right place.

How can I then find out what stage I'm on in the handler.py file so that I can reference the correct database

I've read these:
[Check env variables in serverless.yml file (Serverless Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991250/check-env-variables-in-serverless-yml-file-serverless-framework)
https://forum.serverless.com/t/get-stage-from-handler-js/402/3

and tried using `event.stage` in the handler, which doesn't work offline (haven't tested this deployed)

Answer (score 2):

You can try interpolating stage name with the function name, like this:

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: my_file.my_function
    name: ${sls:stage}-my-function
```

The function name can be obtained by handler code from a [context parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-context.html), property `function_name`.

If you use the convention mentioned above, you can obtain stage name in this way:

```
def my_function(event, context):
   stage = context['function_name'].split('-')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the `environment` key to add environment variables to your function. For example:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    environment:
      APP_STAGE: ${sls:stage}
```

Then you can access it using `os.environ` in Python:

```py
import os

def hello(event, context):
   stage = os.environ.get("APP_STAGE")
```